# WooCommerce automatically sending cancelled orders email

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, cancellation

I received five cancellation notification emails came, all about the same time, and none of them canceled their orders. I called each and every customer and they all told me that they did not cancel the order. The orders were not actually canceled in Wordpress but for some reason, email notifications for cancellation were sent.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: You use some Plug-in to send email? is all update, theme and plug-in?
This people have make the purchase?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action("woocommerce_order_status_changed", "my_custom_notification");

function my_custom_notification($order_id, $checkout=null) {
   global $woocommerce;
   $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
   if($order->status === 'cancelled' ) {
      // Create a mailer
      $mailer = $woocommerce->mailer();

      $message_body = __( 'Hello world!!!' );

      $message = $mailer->wrap_message(
        // Message head and message body.
        sprintf( __( 'Order %s received' ), $order->get_order_number() ), $message_body );

      // Cliente email, email subject and message.
     $mailer->send( $order->billing_email, sprintf( __( 'Order %s received' ), $order->get_order_number() ), $message );
     }

   }
```

You can set your own notification mail on order get cancelled(order status changing to cancelled)